# Present Modally Not Resizing View Properly

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to present a ViewController (embedded in a NavigationController) from a button inside a TableViewController. The presented ViewController should be half the height of the TableViewController. I've tried with the following code below but it doesn't seem to work (Swift 3). Can someone kindly help? thanks!

```
class AddNewRecipeTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    @IBAction func popUpTest(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let pvc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popUpTest") as! UINavigationController

        pvc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.custom
        pvc.transitioningDelegate = self
        self.present(pvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func presentationControllerForPresentedViewController(presented: UIViewController, presentingViewController presenting: UIViewController!, sourceViewController source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
        return HalfSizePresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presenting: presentingViewController)
    }
}

class HalfSizePresentationController : UIPresentationController {
    override var frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView : CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: containerView!.bounds.width, height: containerView!.bounds.height/2)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
func presentationControllerForPresentedViewController(
    presented: UIViewController, 
    presentingViewController presenting: UIViewController!, 
    sourceViewController source: UIViewController) 
    -> UIPresentationController? {
```

That method will never be called, because in Swift 3 it doesn't correspond to any method that Cocoa knows about. (I'm suprised you don't report getting a warning from the compiler about this.)

You probably meant to implement `presentationController(forPresented:presenting:source:)`, like this:

```
func presentationController(
    forPresented presented: UIViewController, 
    presenting: UIViewController?, 
    source: UIViewController) 
    -> UIPresentationController? {
```

But even that won't be called, because you have not set the presented view controller's `modalPresentationStyle` to `.custom`.